# Solving a non-linear ordinary differential equation that includes $\tanh$ and $\cos$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

$$\big(A+B\tanh (Cy+D)\big)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+y=P\cos(\omega x),$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $\omega$ are constant.

I am really looking for an analytical solution to this differential equation. But I really don't know where to start. Can someone please help? Thank you.